# How can you get enough attention to try to reopen a question?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

Back in January 2009, I asked a question on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css-closed). Within a few minutes, it gathered 2 upvotes and 4 answers. And then, it was closed as an exact duplicate by the same person who answered with the accepted answer. To be fair, the answer to both questions was the same, even though they were asked in different ways Since then, it has been made a favorite by three people, and viewed over 21,000 times. The question which came first, only about a week earlier, has been viewed less than 4,000 times. Ironic that I got my only "Famous Question" badge from a closed question.

Clearly, my question was better in terms of Google juice, even though it was technically the "same." It'd be great if it were reopened so that people could add or edit answers, especially because this question relates to a developing technology, CSS3.

However, since it's been "dead" for over a year and a half, I can't figure out a way to get enough attention to it to reopen it. I'm sure there are plenty of other questions like this. Is there a way to get attention to questions like these, besides posting on meta (which I have been reluctant to do)?

**Edit**: Well, no answers as to better solutions than posting on meta, but my question did certainly get enough attention to reopen it. :) Maybe that's just the best solution for now.

Comment: If they are indeed exact dupes, they should be merged together.  I don't know enough about CSS to make that call though.

Comment: wow, that's a lot of views.. congrats! (also a good argument for "allow some duplicates so everyone can find stuff, even if they use different words")

Comment: Is there a way to get enough attention to reopen it? I think you may have figured that out for yourself :)

Comment: Tangentially related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates

Answer (score 3):

I've had a few questions closed and I didn't think they were deserving of that fate.

I did manage to help get a few of them reopened. What was successful was to edit the question to make it more specific or in some way different from the other.

Make sure when you do so, you state in the question that you have edited (be honest!) for this reason.

What happens when you edit a question is that it goes back to the top of the "recent" questions and it will be noticed again. Each reopen vote will put it back up at the top and as long as people are interested it will stay up there. If after a few days it's not reopened, try one more time with a new and better edit. If you can't get it reopened after two edits, then I'd let it go.

But of course, if your question is truly a duplicate, and that is what you really wanted to ask, then it should be closed. Really, you should scan for your question prior to posting it. StackOverflow helps you by showing you possible duplicates after you enter your question's title.