# reCaptcha trying to find out how far it can go?

Tags: discussion, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The reCAPTCHA has become too difficult for humans to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75965/the-recaptcha-has-become-too-difficult-for-humans-to-solve)

As of recently the reCaptcha system has gone crazy for me. I often even cannot read the word you have to enter without some refreshes. And no I'm not talking about the other word in there which you should just neglect or fill in with nazi.

There is currently a question about this [here on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75965/the-recaptcha-has-become-too-difficult-for-humans-to-solve), but that question is more about the other word if I read correctly. Although there is [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142623/155197) in there with some good examples of impossible to read captchas. If this question is an exact dupe after all please close (like I would need to tell you people).

Am I the only one who has problems reading them? Do I need glasses? Last time I checked I was not a robot. Then again maybe I was programmed to never find out I am.

Can something be done to the captcha system to fix this (I know it's a third party)?

Comment: *"Last time I checked I was not a robot."* ... nice try.

Comment: @BradMace Isn't that question about that other word. You know the one you don't have to fill in? "I am tempted to just enter the known word (an easy guess), and leave the other." I cannot read neither of them

Comment: I don't know where you're getting that idea, but you haven't brought up anything new in your question.

Comment: Maybe I do need a pair of glasses, because I read that question as I can read the known word, but not the other.

Comment: Note, I failed the captcha three times today when submitting a comment on the SO blog. It _is_ getting really friggin hard (again). If you haven't experienced it on the site recently, please hold your vote.

Comment: But @Tim, while I've experienced this same thing as well, shouldn't we vote on [the previous question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75965/the-recaptcha-has-become-too-difficult-for-humans-to-solve) and close this one as a duplicate?

Comment: @AaronBertrand That question is old, and third party things change from time to time. If the captcha has become a nuisance again _recently_, well .. Duplicates aren't _always_ duplicates. It's not like the captcha presents a version number.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult, but how will we know when the underlying captcha has changed? If this seems to fix itself and it happens again next week, won't we have no choice but to open a new question about it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand If a third party tool is indeed _blocking_ people from using the system as intended, thus defeating a _ton_ of work that went into an otherwise _extremely considerate_ UI, it's a valid point to raise. I'm not closing this against a question from last year knowing that things have probably changed, and perhaps it needs attention again. As I mentioned, I also experienced this earlier today.

Comment: @Tim I understood, but shouldn't someone bring the existing question to the attention of the devs? In fact a bounty has been opened on the previous question presumably to draw more attention to it. As I suggested, I don't think we need a new copy of the question covering the same issue if it keeps occurring.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Meta is the bug tracker that the community can access. Throwing votes at an old question when the issue happens again is like  screaming into a plastic bag. In this particular case, a new topic is likely warranted, it's not like devs count votes on old issues (or pay attention to bounties at all {proof [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91157/can-we-have-drafts-for-moderator-messages)})

Comment: @TimPost The other question, though old, has been getting a lot of attention lately, including a bounty. I'm not sure if there's much we can do about reCaptcha (we just use whatever Google gives us), though. But we'll see.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that devs care about a bounty, but I'm sure that the admins, mods etc. can make devs aware that an issue has come around again without creating a duplicate question explaining the exact same problem again.

Comment: @AaronBertrand "but I'm sure that the admins, mods etc. can make devs aware that an issue has come around again without creating a duplicate question explaining the exact same problem again" -> how? Commenting on an old thread stating: "I have this problem too" doesn't work.  Should I always add a bounty to such questions? Also doesn't sounds ideal.

Comment: @Petra more context please, I don't know what "how?" means

Comment: @AaronBertrand edited

Comment: The argument about whether or not devs will see this issue is moot, since I just passed it on. The system's working as intended. :)

Comment: @Petra as far as I know you and I can't get the devs' attention directly. But admins and mods certainly can. I don't think a bounty is helpful, but editing the existing question might be more useful to indicate that, even though the question was originally submitted over a year ago, the issue is still present.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Tried that in the past didn't come much out of it :)

Comment: @Petra was it the same kind of scenario (where it was something functional with the site that only the owners can do something about)? Can you provide an example? And/or any example where doing so failed but creating a new, duplicate question worked?

Comment: I didn't create a new post I just thought: meh @AaronBertrand

Comment: @AaronBertrand Let me write a question on this topic, because this commenting thing really isnt suited :)

Comment: @Petra, for your new question: beware of [How can you get enough attention to try to reopen a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65314/how-can-you-get-enough-attention-to-try-to-reopen-a-question) and the FAQ item [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143231/how-to-make-the-devs-mods-aware-of-a-problem-which-is-already-mentioned-in-an-o