# Do closed questions get deleted automatically after some time?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

If my question is closed, for being unclear and vague, then would it get deleted by default after a few days?

**EDIT 1:**

Another thing I want to know is what is the reason, generally, to delete a question after it's closed? (I'm assuming before being deleted a question is closed.)

**EDIT 2:**

Are we notified or warned about the question about to get deleted before it actually gets done? I mean in case we want to save the answer and stuff then how do we do that?

Comment: I don't know, but I like the idea of keeping it. Imagine that it was deleted because of exact duplicate, but you couldn't find the other question with the words in mind. It would be good to find your question pointing to the other question. A closed question in this case would be a link.

Comment: @BrunoLM: That's basically the reason I am asking it here, because if you find that question and answers helpful then sometimes you might wanna go back to that question. If it's closed it's still ok, but if it's deleted then it takes away even the two cents which could be helpful to the question owner and may be some other people.

Comment: Note that deleting questions closed as duplicates [is discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates). It's still *done* - duplicating another off-topic question doesn't give you a pass - but it's less likely.

Comment: @Shog9: What about deleting of a 'vague', 'not orginial' question? Is it done generally or not?

Comment: @Harpreet: depends on whether enough people care to vote on it. Some do, some don't.

Comment: @Harpeet: as one data point, I vote to delete "bad" questions that have no useful answers. If a bad question has useful answers, I tend to leave it around - might be helpful to someone. For example, underspecified questions requiring mind reading - we have some incredible mind readers on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*If* there's no activity, questions with a score <=0 can be [deleted automatically after a (fairly generous) period of time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81887/what-happens-to-unanswered-questions-from-deleted-accounts/82408#82408).

[Also, once closed, users with >= 10K reputation points can vote to delete it after 48 hours, and users with 20K can vote to delete immediately...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean). Moderators can and sometimes will delete questions at any time - closed questions are often deleted on sight as part of a cleanup effort.

Therefore, you should generally view a closed question as one that has been [nominated for deletion](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/i-move-to-close-this-question/). If you think there's a good reason for it to stick around, say something.

Comment: "Therefore, you should generally view a closed question as one that has been nominated for deletion. If you think there's a good reason for it to stick around, say something."

Wow nice. How often does that happen to old closed questions though?

Comment: Depends on the site, and how much it irritates someone. Moderators will occasionally do a sweep through the site and delete many closed questions as part of a cleanup effort, so even if you think a question has been overlooked it might still disappear... Think of a closed question as sitting on death row... Maybe it'll hang around for years, but unless you can get a reprieve it's eventually going to die.

Answer (score 1):

No, and unless a question is really kind of harmful, it should remain not deleted so that someone else trying to ask a similar question will notice there was one but is closed and therefore may reconsider posting at all.