# Should I change an answered question's title to make it more general?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, duplicate-questions

Say I have this question and its answers

[C++ convert int and string to char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766150/c-convert-int-and-string-to-char)..

And then this question is asked

[C++ converting an int to an array of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807635/c-converting-an-int-to-an-array-of-chars)

Would it make sense to alter the title of the first question to

> How to convert int and string to char* or a char array in C++

Then it's easier to refer  to the second question.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates).

Comment: I'm not asking about deleting the question. Rather just altering the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO no. If there is an exact duplicated is because the OP didn't have the words in mind to search the other question. Keeping both formats would provide more ways to get on the same result.

[More info here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates).