# deleting own question, when it's closed

Tags: bug, closed-questions, self-delete

As far as I know, OP should be able to delete **his own question** when it has no (upvoted) answers. However, if that question is closed, OP is prevented from deleting **his own question** `to allow possible reopening`.

Seems that in this case condition of question being closed takes precedence over being own question, which IMO is flawed.

Answer (score 4):

I think there should be an exception for heavily downvoted questions, which cannot be deleted by the OP because they were closed.

Obviously if the question has been downvoted several times it's not useful. But the OP can't delete it easily so it's a sort of "mark of shame".

Comment: High-rep users can vote to delete these questions immediately.  Failing that, a moderator flag would serve the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

[Do not delete duplicates!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32311/147423)

> Only off-topic or unintelligible questions should be deleted; duplicates are quite useful to keep around.

Only 10k users can vote to delete duplicates, and it is only done when the above is true.

Dupes are good, mostly should stick around. When you become a "trusted" user you can vote to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug, but the expected behavior.

The idea is that the question could have been wrongly closed, or that just needs to be edited to be re-opened; I think that giving the time to somebody to check if the question was closed for a valid reason is generally a good idea. I would not surely want a good question be deleted just because was wrongly closed.

I can also imagine the OPs are not immediately allowed to delete their own closed questions to avoid they delete the questions as reaction to the questions being closed.

20k users can immediately vote to delete the question, once it has been closed. If the OP really wants the question to be deleted, the question can be flagged for moderation attention; if the OP explains the reason for deleting the question, moderators generally delete the question (if it is a valid reason).

Comment: That should be up to the author of the question to decide.

Comment: It's not always up to the OP to decide; see the case of a question with answers.

Comment: which isn't relevant, as the bug report is about question without answers, and being closed they will not have answers. Ever.

Comment: @vartec It is relevant to say that such decision is not always left to the OP; if the decision is not left to the OP in one case, then there should be a reason if the decision is not immediately left to the OP in the second case. In the second case, the question could be wrongly closed, then re-opened, and have answers.