# Why is "Get current URL with javascript" closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Four hours ago, this post was closed:
[Get current URL in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript)

And i dont understand why it makes sense to close down a post two years old stating that it is a duplicate of another post that is also two years old, when the post in question has 80 times the number of views, 30 times the number of upvotes, and is the top result when searching for this topic in google.

Is it a strict "we are redirecting this because the original one was posted before this one"
or what?

Comment: No redirection is happening. That is, a message is coming up, but a 301/302 is not what is occuring.

Comment: What do you suggest?  Reverse the close as duplicate so that the older question points to the one you linked?

Comment: It doesn't matter which one has more votes. It matters which one was asked *first*.

Comment: @animuson I disagree. If the later one is 1.) worded better or 2.) has better answers, it deserves to be the original. Having been first shouldn't be the only factor when deciding how to dupe-close

Comment: @animuson: Well, it does matter some.  The master question should be the one that is more canonical.

Comment: So merge the answers into the one that was asked first.

Comment: @animuson I'd like that, too, but merging often doesn't work due to differences in the way the question was asked (despite it being the same question).

Comment: I would also like to say that the top answer on the post that i linked is a much better, more precise answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey can't those two be merged and everyone will be happy?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: I don't see a compelling reason to do so.  Both questions stand quite happily on their own; the newer one is a duplicate of the older.  The relative quality of the questions and answers is about the same; the newer post must have gotten Redditted, which is why it has so many more votes.  Merging the two posts won't improve the clarity of either.

Answer (score 1):

Could be the post was flagged as a duplicate by a user and the moderator acted on the flag.

One of the users who answers even mentions it is a duplicate

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1034697/321505

> The same question has been asked less than 24 hours ago.

So to answer your question

> Is it a strict "we are redirecting this because the original one was posted before this one" or what?

Yes, pretty much, just because it's old doesn't give it a get out of jail free pass. Community policy has changed since two years ago and as such all questions must abide by it or have some sort of notice signifying why it has remained open.

A duplicate is a duplicate. The next logical step would be to merge answers so that it's all in one place.

Comment: It shouldn't necessarily be merged for the exact reason the closed question was found by the OP more easily- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates

Comment: @davidsleeps: Merging != deleting. Merging pushes them together and **redirects** the old question to the duplicated one. Deleting just flat-out removes it.

Comment: @davidsleeps that's up for debate based on the OP query and whether or not the views were not due to say sharing on other sites. OP didn't really say what his query was.

Comment: @animuson cool, that makes the most sense then...

Answer (score 1):

I believe your concern is more that the newer, "more popular" question is closed as an exact duplicate *rather than the earlier question* as opposed to it being closed at all.  Unfortunately, this is how "exact duplicate" works:  a question can be a duplicate only of an earlier question, not of a later one, no matter how "popular" the later question is.

Comment: I reserve the right to declare as the master the question that is better.