# Preserve duplicate question titles (even after the duplicate questions are merged)

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do not delete duplicates!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates)

When a duplicate question on Stack Exchange is deleted or merged with another question, is the question's title deleted from Stack Overflow, or is the title kept, as a sort of "redirect page" for navigational purposes? I think deleting entire duplicate questions (along with their titles) would be counter-productive from a search engine user's perspective - alternate titles for questions are often useful for navigational purposes, since many questions can be worded in different ways. Are alternate titles of questions lost forever when the duplicate questions are merged, or are they retained  (for the benefit of search engine users?)

Comment: @Robotnik Yeah, I think that's a duplicate - hopefully this question's title will be retained for navigational purposes.