# What actions/interactions cause a question to move to the top of the list?

Tags: support, questions, comments, answers, last-activity

What actions or interaction on a question cause it to move up / timestamp refresh? For example, I know that for the following...

- Posting an answer (**yes**)
- Voting up a comment (**no**)
- Flagging the question (**no**)
- Voting to close the question (**no**)
- Accepting an answer (**no**)

Ok, what about these?

- Editing the question?
- Editing an answer?
- Posting a comment on the question?
- Posting a comment on an answer?
- Deleting an answer?
- Reopening the question?

What else have I missed? To be more concise, someone may just post a list of **which actions cause a question to refresh/bump**.

Comment: Damn, I did not think of using the word "bumped". However, I'll let this question close rather than get deleted, because I had a hard time finding that one.

Comment: Having an extra [signpost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates) is no problem.  Hopefully the next person will find the answer without having to write out a whole question.