# Deletion/merger of a particular duplicate question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, merged-questions

[It is known that deletion of duplicate questions is not encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32311/216721), but in this particular case, I feel that the question needs to be either deleted or merged with its duplicate.

The question in concern is [How can this code throw a NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20874826/2024761)

Why I feel that this should be either deleted or merged:

1. According to the OP of the question, this question wasn't meant to be a real one. It was just a vote bait to get a hat for the Winterbash, [as admitted by the OP himself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874826/how-can-this-code-throw-a-nullpointerexception#comment31324011_20874826).

   > @PM77-1 I admit it's a quiz. It's vote bait for a hat. I only need a vote count of 1 :/ – Bohemian♦
2. Though duplicates can be useful as users tend to use different search words, this question doesn't exactly have a title which would be used by anybody(pretty much).

   > How can this code throw a NullPointerException?
3. And the most important reason why I feel this needs to disappear into eternity is, the OP of this question under concern is [one of the newly elected moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223009/216721), [Bohemian♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian). I'm sure that he did not intend to keep this around for a while himself(may have missed this one) because it was never meant to be a question. And not just that, for the good member(moderator now!) he is, of the community for a long time now, this question could shown him in bad light and also, not reflect the quality of questions we maintain here on SO. Also being a moderator, his posts should set an example for the plenty of new users joining the site daily...
4. He is the OP of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759917/2024761) of the duplicate question, so I really doubt if he really didn't know about the error situation posted in the question.

Since the question has two answers and one is accepted as well, I feel it would be unfair to the users who posted the answers. That is why I hope some moderator can take a call on whether to delete or merge this question.

*Note:* I really like *Bohemian* (for all his contributions here) and that is another reason why I don't want such a bad question to be sticking on to him.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvotes my other posts along with this if they do not agree with just this.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian - I am just surprised by those few users who rage downvote at times. Also, regarding your other statement, actually he did that just to get a hat, and it was never meant to be a actual question and that is why I felt that it could be removed after all.

Comment: I downvoted because I disagree with your premise (The question needs to be deleted or merged), not because it was a bad question. It was a very good question. I've upvoted another of your good questions that I agree with to compensate.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - I don't mind downvotes on my post. Just that some people downvote other posts of mine seeing this post which is what bothers me. Anyways, I don't care about votes anymore(I used to before, though) :)

Comment: The question in question no longer exists.

Comment: It does if you have 10k on Stack Overflow ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the criteria for merging a question is whether or not the answers can apply to either question.  Look at the answers to both questions; does the answer to 'Why does this code throw a null pointer exception?' easily apply to the source question?

No.

Now turn it around. Do the answers to the source question ("Logical short-circuiting operators") apply well to Bohemian's question?

No.

They apply -- just not well. A user who is searching and comes upon Bohemian's question has a direct answer to his question, whereas there's a *lot* more footwork for a newer programmer to figure out how the general question (logical short-circuit operators) applies in his specific instance (a null pointer exception).

That having been said, we all have goofy questions. Except Jon Skeet.

I've updated the question by removing the chatty comments and the obsolete comments.

#### Deletion

Whether or not the Community wants to delete it is up to them. As a moderator, I normally don't summarily delete questions that have upvoted answers . It's not fair to the people who spent their time helping the OP, and it's not fair to destroy useful content unilaterally (unless I can point to another place where that content really is duplicated).

As far as downvoting: As long as the question is well asked, why are you downvoting it? That question is much better (and better asked) than many questions we get that aren't voted on at all (or are upvoted).

You may not like his motivation, but it's still a useful, well asked question.

Comment: I agree to your criteria regarding the merger, but can you please it a bit more on why it shouldn't be deleted either? specially when the OP confessed that it was just for an hat.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ I also updated my answer with the content you requested.