# Is there a way to know how long is left until I can post another question?

Tags: support, posting, question-restrictions

When I try to add a second question to a S.E. community and get this:

[image]

It makes me a bit depressed. S.E. has great design and UX but I really wish there was a little counter to tell you when you can post next.

Do I have to go hunt my last question through my profile page?
Or what's the best way to know in how many minutes I'll be able to post next?

Comment: Oh, it is! You're right. It wasn't one if the suggested "similar questions" and I didn't find it by search either. Should I delete?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32314/215590 - it's your choice