# What happened to my old question?

Tags: support, voting, deleted-answers

I posted a question 18 months ago or so on SO, got a couple of votes. The question has been deleted - I can't find it. It's just gone - can't google it either. I see 2 much newer questions by other people, essentially the same question as mine, and they have 50 and 68 votes... I don't care about the voting, it's always going to be unfair to someone, but where the hell did my question go?

Comment: Can you point us to the two questions that weren't deleted or tell us what your question was?

Comment: My question from yesterday also got ignored due to the too intelligent "interesting" feature that apparently decided it was not  interesting enough. Never mind, I registered on other forums in the Internet and asked there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646707/something-better-than-net-reflector.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?  [Only one of your questions ever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205927/how-to-get-google-to-show-table-of-contents) was *not* self-deleted.  The other 22 were deleted by you...and none of those include the word "reflector".

Comment: @Nick -- The question I posted was asking about open source alternatives to Reflector. It's gone from my list of questions, and apparently it is nowhere in your database. It was one of my earliest questions, and might have been asked about 2 years ago actually... Just pointing this out, I don't care - we're good...

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector) helpful.

Comment: @Pau - We don't hard delete questions except in extraordinary circumstances...it's likely this question was posted under another account, or you're mis-remembering...I don't know any reason your question would be hard deleted, unless there was some data corruption issue we wouldn't do this.

Comment: Is there any chance it could have been *migrated* and the stub removed, or *merged* with one of the others and the edit history somehow not show this?

Comment: @gnostradamus - even in migration and merging cases, the stub stays around.  Its soft-deleted only, the DB record remains.

Comment: @Kevin: merging works that way *[now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16437/when-merging-questions-leave-the-duplicate-one-as-a-placeholder)*... But if he posted it two years ago, and it was merged, I believe it would have disappeared without a trace. That said, there's no merge record on the post I found, so if this is what happened then it must have been with something else.

Comment: @Shog9 - good point, I forgot merging ever worked that way.

Answer (score 1):

Moderators can search deleted questions, so probably flag one of your question for moderator attention, and ask for it?

Comment: My question also just got deleted. I would find it useful to get an email or any other kind of notification with an explanation why it was deleted and where to go from here. I knew there was a potential for my question to be deleted because it was kind of off topic although still related to the network (code review). What's bugging me, that I as an author can't see the deleted question and talk with a moderator about it. Where is the right exchange to request such features?